# Stop Designer-Palete to poping up when some xml view is clicked

Tags: android-studio

I am a bit annoying from Designer-Palete in Android Studio:

> Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 Build
> #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639, built on May 12, 2023 Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694 aarch64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. macOS 13.2.1 GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old
> Generation Memory: 2048M Cores: 12 Metal Rendering is ON Registry:
> external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
> ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
> gradle.version.catalogs.dynamic.support=true
>
> Non-Bundled Plugins:
> com.intellij.marketplace (222.4459.28)

When I click on some view in the Design tab the palette appears and hides everything

> Look in the screenshot

[image]

I should close each instance of it before access to the view it self. Is there a way to stop this or remove the palette at all?